# Do players using Renaissance firearms need to keep track of gunpowder as well as bullets, and if so, how many shots is a horn of gunpowder good for?

Tags: dnd-5e, firearms, ammunition

I'm running a campaign where the Renaissance era firearms on page 267-268 of the DMG exist. I notice that the rules for gunpowder are under "explosives" and not firearms, but still includes the quote, "gunpowder is chiefly used to propel a bullet out of the barrel of a pistol or rifle."

Do my players need to keep track of both bullets as well as gunpowder, or do they just need to keep track of the bullets? Also, how many shots would a horn of gunpowder be good for, as made available in the DMG on page 268. The second question only applies if they need to be keeping track of gunpowder.

Answer (score 7):

No, they just need to track bullets.

lets look at the description of firearm ammunition in the DMG, "renaissance and modern firearms use bullets" no mention of powder is given, and as has been stated many times there are no hidden rules.

This is not unrealistic either, often bullets were packed together with the correct measure of powder all wrapped in paper that also acted as wadding to keep the bullet in place. this was the norm from the Napoleonic war to until metal cartridges replaced paper cartridges. So we can assume the powder is included in the "bullet"

[image]

Comment: I still use paper cartridges to this day. Of course in working replicas of historical weapons. Two notes for realism - paper cartridges include also felt between the ball and powder, and ball is covered with grease. Also, they usually don't contain any percussion material so user needs powder horn for flintlock - but amount used is so small that my coach was using pocket watch sized "horn" for that, so I wouldn't bother with tracking.

Comment: @Mołot you can also load the pan directly from the cartridges, this is why biting the end of the cartridge off was a common practice, and even part of military instruction.

Comment: Not really, as far as I was taught. You bit the end of, poured powder down the barrel, used paper instead of felt, and hammered the ball down. That way cleaning was easier and cartridges were cheaper. But for the main charge you need FFg or Fg (coarse) powder and for a pan FFFFg (finest) one. Using FFg or FFFg for everything is doable, but not reliable. Speaking from my experience and experience of my teachers ;)

Comment: @Mołot and yet pouring from the cartridge was what the military actually did, in combat fast reload was extremely important. even given as instruction in arms manuals for the Napoleonic military. https://www.militaryheritage.com/loading1777frenchmusket.htm

Comment: @John one military, it seems. Nice to know, but looks more like an aberration by a cost-saving Napoleon, the same who skimped on warm clothes and food when sending troops to Russia. Still, D&D is but a game so no need to worry too much about pan powder.

Comment: The way I understand it, finely ground gunpowder flashes faster and hotter, so you have a better chance of the flash going down the touch-hole with enough heat to set off the main charge. It *can* work with plain gunpowder, it's just less reliable. I wouldn't be surprised if militaries that depended on massed musket formations were okay with a relatively high failure rate that would not be acceptable to a hunter, who really needs the gun to fire successfully the first time since a flash-in-the-pan would scare off the prey. A soldier can reprime and try again, the enemy isn't going anywhere.

Comment: (Of course while repriming you want to make sure the gun remains pointed downrange because hang-fire is a thing and you really don't want to be looking down the barrel if it unexpectedly fires a couple seconds late!)

Comment: @Mołot the British did it too, it really was common practice https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a334854d55b415d1d9344a8/t/5e8aa0a206e7117ae536fb9a/1586143395749/British+Manual+of+Arms%2C+2nd+Ed.+%281%29.pdf

Comment: Despite not needing to keep track of the powder, for immersion reasons can the gunpowder be ruined, lost, or stolen? Does the powder horn "Exist" in game?

Comment: @Aww_Geez well you can buy one so obviously it exists, as for everything else it is also always up to the DM. in real life direct powder and thus powder horns were preferred by hunters where speed of reloading is less important than reliability. many did not even use paper cartridges because they were more expansive than just hand loading each time.